# How can I work with both xml/json and form-urlencoded?

Tags: json, xml, forms, jax-rs

I'm trying to test using same method for both `application/(xml|json)` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I have an entity class looks like this

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
    @XmlElement private int age;
    @XmlElement private String name;
}
```

With following method,

```java
@POST
@Consumes({APPLICATION_XML, APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response createSingle(@NotNull final Person person) {
}
```

Both `application/xml` and `application/json` work fine.

Now when I change the `Person` class like this

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Person {
    @XmlElement @FormParam("age") private int age;
    @XmlElement @FormParam("name" private String name;
}
```

and tries with following (changed) method.

```java
@POST
@Consumes({APPLICATION_XML, APPLICATION_JSON, APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
public Response createSingle(@NotNull @BeanParam final Person person) {
}
```

Only `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` works.

Is this normal by specification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read the specification and there is no impediment for a method to accept xml, json and form-params. However I'm afraid this should be a detail dependent on the implementation

Since the method to execute for the same URL can be determined through the content-type, I suggest separating the interfaces

```
 @POST
 @Path("/creatSingle")
 @Consumes({APPLICATION_XML, APPLICATION_JSON})
  public Response createSingleXmlJson(@NotNull final Person person) {
  }

 @POST
 @Path("/creatSingle")
 @Consumes({APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
 public Response createSingleForm(@NotNull @BeanParam final Person person) {
 }
```

With this approach you can also simplify the response generation, because the response probably is different in each case